# Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot 2 of the same versions

Tags: 12.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my PC since 12.04 felt super unstable this is a slight improvement.. any way when I start up my PC there are 2 Ubuntus in boot up that run the same OS nothing in difference, along with Windows Vista so there is something like this:

```
*Windows Vista
*Ubuntu  -
           (Problem)
*Ubuntu  -
```

How can I just have one Ubuntu and please don't tell me i need to have everything obliterated! I don't want to remove Ubuntu all over again its super annoying and a pain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use easyBCD to delete your old ubuntu bootloader

- just download and install it
- after finish open the application and go to "edit boot menu" and you
  can see the bootloader exist in your pc
- click your old (problem) ubuntu and delete it (make sure you delete
  the right ubuntu)
- save it and restart your PC

now if there is no problem your bootloader will only just 2 (your vista & your ubuntu)
Good luck